# DSC Resource xADUser Fails to Log Into Server

Tags: powershell, powershell-dsc

I'm running DSC script on a Domain Controller in order to add users.  In my case xADUser fails with the following error.

```
PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_xADUser  failed to execute Test-TargetResource functionality with 
error message: 
Either the target name is incorrect or the server has 
rejected the client credentials.
```

This is the portion of the script that adds the user.

```
foreach ($svcAcct in  $srvcAccounts){
            xADUser ("AddSvcAcct-" + $svcAcct){
                DomainName = $DomainName
                UserName = $svcAcct
                Password = $DomainAdminCredential
                Ensure = "Present"
                CommonName = $svcAcct
                UserPrincipalName = ("{0}@{1}" -f $svcAcct, $DomainName)
                DisplayName = "$svcAcct"
                CannotChangePassword = $true
                DependsOn = "[xADDomain]CreateForest"
                Description = "SharePoint Service Account"
                DomainAdministratorCredential = $DomainAdminCredential
                Enabled = $true
                PasswordAuthentication = "Default"
                PasswordNeverExpires = $true
                DomainController = "DC1"
            }

        }
```

Comment: I assume that `$DomainAdminCredential` is a `[PSCredential]` object. If not, then that's your issue. If it is try adding `PsDscRunAsCredential = $DomainAdminCredential`

Answer (score 0):

Since I am running this code on the Domain Controller I simplified the Resource declaration by removing DomainAdministratorCredential and other optional parameters and it then worked.

```
xADUser ("AddSvcAcct-" + $svcAcct){
  DomainName = $DomainName
  UserName = $svcAcct
  Password = $DomainUserCredential
  Ensure = "Present"
  PasswordNeverExpires = $true
  Path = $ou
  DependsOn = @("[xADOrganizationalUnit]SrvcAcctOUCreate")
}
```